# Finding Clustered/Consecutive Values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to find values in an Excel spread sheet where numbers greater than 0 will be highlighted. However, those highlighted must be clustered, consecutive numbers which should be (at least) three in a row.

For example:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
34
0
0
0
**156**
**190**
**2300**
**190**
**34**
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
17732
0
0
0
0
**2000**
**2900**
**1000**
0
0
0
0
```

Numbers in Bold should have their whole rows highlighted/coloured in Excel.

Is there a simple method to do this? Preferably without VBA.

**EXTRA:**
Find numbers that almost have the 3-cluster rule. For example:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
**156**
**0**
**190**
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
17732
0
0
0
0
**2000**
**0**
**3000**
**1000**
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Are you able to add extra columns to the data? It is easier if you can because you can then use formulae in those columns to help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "add extra columns"? I have (literally) thousands of values to go through and that sounds very laborious.

Comment: So are they always separated by one space? Are they all in one cell? One column? Do you need to retain the non-highlighted numbers?  If each number is in one column and its own cell, can't you just use some conditional formatting? When you say clustered you mean consecutive? I tried cleaning up the formatting in your question, it was making it very difficult to understand.

Comment: Assuming you are using a newish verison of Excel. Add a row at the top to hold a column title, add a title to your data, "Data" for example. Then turn the whole thing into a "table" using the button that is on the HOME rubbon tab. Then you can start typing a formula in the next column and Excel will fill every row for you - very little effort. All this depends on how you get the data in to the worksheet. Hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your values are in a single column, column **A**:

[image]

We want rows *11,12,13* hi-lighted.

Running this short macro:

```
Sub KolorRows()
    Dim N As Long, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim i As Long, K As Long, v As Long, r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r1 = Nothing
    Set r2 = Nothing
    K = 0

    For i = 1 To N
        Set r = Cells(i, "A")
        v = r.Value
        If v = 0 Then
            Set r1 = Nothing
            Set r2 = Nothing
            K = 0
        Else
            Select Case K
                Case 0
                    K = K + 1
                    Set r1 = r
                Case 1
                    K = K + 1
                    Set r2 = r
                Case 2
                    K = 0
                    Union(r1, r2, r).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                    Set r1 = Nothing
                    Set r2 = Nothing
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**